Multiview spectral clustering
i have been working on implementing multi view spectral clustering, initially i have implemented spectral clustering with one view and it worked fine, now with multiple views i have a problem initializing the a(v) which is the variable that reflects the contribution/importance of the v-th view, initializing the the a(v) for the views with similar values wouldn't help, there might be view that contains better information about the datapoints, so how is this usually done ?
I tried a loop for convergence of the values of a(v) (for now am assuming the convergence at the 100th iteration) that i got from chatgpt but i don't understand how it works and its not giving any meaningful results :
for i in range(100):
    L_combinee_vue = np.power(a1,r)*L_vue1 + np.power(a2,r)*L_vue2 + np.power(a3,r)*L_vue3 + np.power(a4,r)*L_vue4
    eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eigh(L_combinee_vue)
    f = eigvecs[:, -3:]  
    a1 = 1 /  np.trace(np.dot(f.T, np.dot(L_vue1, f))) # a rechercher                     
    a2 = 1 /  np.trace(np.dot(f.T, np.dot(L_vue2, f)))
    a3 = 1 /  np.trace(np.dot(f.T, np.dot(L_vue3, f)))
    a4 = 1 /  np.trace(np.dot(f.T, np.dot(L_vue4, f)))

fnormalized = normalize(f)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=random_state)
clustered_data = km.fit_predict(fnormalized)

